# jQuery .val using ID selector undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form action="javascript:message();">
<input type="text" id="#msg" value='test'>
</form>
```

This is a simple form I made. Now when I call my JS function using this code it works (only one input can be accessed though):

```
function message() {
    alert($('input').val());
}
```

But using this code doesn't work (alerts Undefined):

```
function message() {
    alert($('#msg').val());
}
```

I have really no clue what to do and I have been looking for hours...

Comment: Remove the `#` from the id attribute in your HTML. You're confusing the ID value with the selector syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the `id` attribute shouldn't start with a `#`:

```
<form action="javascript:message();">
    <input type="text" id="msg" value='test'>
</form>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XrJjU/

---

If, for whatever reason, there *is* a `#` in the id, you'll have to escape it in your selector:

```
$('#\\#msg').val();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7P5ER/

Comment: *facepalm* it was late... i'm sorry :S